# Special characters seem ot "kill" the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

**Problem:**

being a german dev I often have Umlaute in my strings, comments, etc. When pasting those into the rails console though it renders the prompt unresponding. It can only be resolved by quitting and restarting the rails-console

**Request:**

Any way I can configure or fix the console so it accepts special chars as input

**Example:**

```
    # paste in console to render it useless
    def is_a_test
      puts "it's a string with ä ö and ü"
    end
```

leads to this on console:

```
irb(main):004:0>     # paste in console to render it useless
=> nil
irb(main):005:0>     def is_a_test
irb(main):006:1>       puts "it's a string with
irb(main):007:1"
irb(main):008:1" ^C
irb(main):008:0>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cannot reproduce:
```$ irb                                                                                                                                              
2.6.3 :001 > # paste in console to render it useless
 => nil 
2.6.3 :002 >     def is_a_test
2.6.3 :003?>         puts "it's a string with ä ö and ü"
2.6.3 :004?>       end
 => :is_a_test 
2.6.3 :005 > 
```

Going to need more info. My suspicion is it's some kind of encoding problem.

Comment: This works for me: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv3Aa.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv3Aa.png) Double-check your copy-paste settings with your terminal application to make sure it's receiving and passing the encoded values correctly. I'm using Alacritty - so if you're on *nix, you could try using this terminal instead to see if that helps you.

Comment: What versions of Ruby and Ruby on Rails do you use?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: i tried it on my local system and also got it working there. went on to check terminal settings, my colleague's terminal settings, then my `locale` on that server. turns out that is misconfigured and has "POSIX" for everything.